# GWT: In an MVP design, should the underlying page layout be a considered a view?

Tags: gwt, mvp, uibuilder

I have been following the GWT MVP tutorial (https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/mvp-architecture-2) and while it all makes a lot of sense, I have some trouble taking it from the example they explain to a larger scale application.

In particular, I would like to use a DockLayoutPanel to have a separate navigation, content and header section. What I'm struggling with is primarily the question of: where does the main dock panel live? Is it a view with it's own associated presenter? Does it constitute a special case where I don't want to use a view as this is really just the fundamental page layout?

It would be greatly appreciated to get some practical insights from people having faced a similar issue before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for something related, I stumbled across another thread that asks a similar question and was quite insightful for me:
[GWT MVP - maintaining multiple displays that are separate of one another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879640/gwt-mvp-maintaining-multiple-displays-that-are-separate-of-one-another)

Answer (score 1):

Well I think as always it depends.

But I would recommend to create a `View`  (i.e. *MainPageView*) with it's own associated `Presenter` (i.e. *MainPagePresenter*) even when there is almost no business logic and the `View` only defines the layout of the application.
Maybe in the future there will be some business logic.
For example if you want to show alerts or notification popups to a user you will probably do this in this `View`.
So your `MainPagePresenter` will listen for Notification events on the global `EventBus` and once an event is fired from any nested `Presenter` it will display a notification popup in the `MainPageView`.

Another use case would be if you want to display breadcrumbs in the north panel.
Of course you could create a separate `Presenter` for breadcrumbs but IMHO that's too much overengineering. You could however easily do that in the `MainPagePresenter`

I am using [GWTP](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/) as my MVP framework and there it is really trivial to create View/Presenter pairs and it also supports nested `PresenterWidgets` which you can for example embed in any panel of your `DockLayoutPanel`